# PhoneGap installation and creation of PhoneGap-based application

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have installed PhoneGap successfully on my MAC pc(IOS 10.5.8, SDK 3.1.2).Try to create a new PhoneGap-based application, included the PhoneGap framework and copied the required files in www folder. Now I am trying to run the application but it gives build error:

**Invalid value 'com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0' for GCC_VERSION**

Please suggest solution for this, if i am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need Snow Leopard (10.6) or higher with Xcode 4.0 or higher to use this version of PhoneGap since it requires LLVM.